# XmlSerialization with a singleton

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

Serialization woes [continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663948/xmlserializer-with-dependencies-results-in-null-reference-exception)...

I'm trying to serialize a class, instances of which share between them common objects (a binder of sorts). So, objects A, B, C share object Binder1, and objects D and E - Binder2, and so on... I'm serializing objects A,B,C,D,E. Typically, this binder object is passed in a constructor - not with the serializer though, since it needs a parameterless constructor.

ISeriazable seems to have something that works for singletons - `IObjectReference` interface, where the method `GetRealObject` can be used to return a reference to the newly created singleton. But, it doesn't look like `XmlSerializer` cares about this interface.

So, how should I go about serializing/deserializing these objects?

**EDIT**: I'm almost ready to give up on this question, since I just discovered this [question discussed on a forum](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/446757-singletons-serialization) from 2006 **(!!)** between two giants @JonSkeet and @MarcGravell, where the answer is essentially **no** for XmlSerializer. I'll keep this question open for a bit longer just in case things have changed in the past 7 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this natively with XmlSerializer. I did find an [old thread](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/446757-singletons-serialization) between Jon Skeet and Marc Gravell that basically says that you can't do this the same way that you could with ISerializable and IObjectReference.

The way I had to make this work was along the following lines:

- Add a Guid field to the Binder object (i.e. the common object shared by multiple objects)
- During deserialization, use a static Dictionary and either use an already registered Binder object with the same Guid or add a new Binder object to the static dictionary for others to link against.