# Serialize type safe enums for web api response?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, enums

I'm having difficulties with getting my model sent back in a correct way from my web api.

I'm getting this exception message: `The 'ObjectContent`1`' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.`

This is what my model looks like:

```
public class ValidationCreditReport
    {
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        public CreditRecommendation recommendationSecure { get; set; }
        public CreditRecommendation recommendationUnsecure { get; set; }
        public CreditOutlook creditOutlook { get; set; }
        public IndicativeRating indicativeCorporateRating { get; set; }
        public IndicativeRating indicativeSeniorUnsecured { get; set; }
        public IndicativeRating indicativeSeniorSecured { get; set; }
        public Currency currency { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return companyId + " " + companyName + " " + recommendationSecure.Name + " " + recommendationUnsecure.Name + " " +
                creditOutlook.Name + " " + indicativeCorporateRating.Name + " " + indicativeSeniorSecured.Name + " " + indicativeSeniorSecured.Name + " " + currency.Name;
        }
    }
```

And here is my enum types:

```
public class CreditRecommendation
    { 
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        private CreditRecommendation (string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public static CreditRecommendation Buy = new CreditRecommendation("Buy");
        public static CreditRecommendation Sell = new CreditRecommendation("Sell");
        public static CreditRecommendation Hold = new CreditRecommendation("Hold");
        public static CreditRecommendation NoRating = new CreditRecommendation("NoRating");

        public static CreditRecommendation FromName(string name)
        {
            switch (name)
            {
                case "Buy":
                    return Buy;
                case "Sell":
                    return Sell;
                case "Hold":
                    return Hold;
                case "NoRating":
                    return NoRating;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Provided name invalid: " + name);
            }
        }
    };
```

The rest of the enum models look the same but just different names and a few more or less options under their respective switch cases.

What I've been trying to do now is to write my own `toString()` function that calls the enums `.name` and appends them into a normal string. I was thinking of just hardcoding this string into a json string. But I don't think this is the correct way to tackle this problem and handle this.

and finally here's where I actually try to send my data back:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetLastPublishedData(String companyName)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = CreateSqlConnection())
            {
                using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var service = CreateCreditService(connection, transaction);
                        var msg = service.ValidateAndPrepareCreditReport(companyName);
                        var result = CreateValidationCreditReport(msg);
                        transaction.Commit();
                        return this.Request.CreateResponse<ValidationCreditReport>(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
                    }
                    catch{
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

I've walked through the whole project and the problem seems to stem from my enums and them not being able to serialize.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are talking about enums but then you are showing us classes. I do not understand you approach, why are you using a class for representing a simple enumerative?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I'm inherating some of this code from a former coworker that has quit. I'm not 100% sure about all of the design choices but I'm trying my best to understand them.

Comment: @Gurkang - you tagged this question [tag:json] but the exception error message mentions XML.  Which are you using?  You are trying to do singleton serialization, which works differently in each serializer (or not at all for `XmlSerializer`, see [XmlSerialization with a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667164).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding an empty constructor for each enum class.

So for the CreditRecommendation class it looks like this now:

```
public CreditRecommendation() { }
```

Comment: Although this works, it defeats the purpose of the pattern, which is not being able to initiate the class with invalid values due to the private constructor. I think the conclusion of Federico is correct; for serialization purposes this pattern is not what you want; either switch it out or map it to a better suited model.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see your code needs refactoring. Using classes for enumerative types is really a bad design choice with no advantage.

Refactor your types and use simple enums instead:

```
public enum CreditRecommendation {
    Buy,
    Sell,
    Hold,
    NoRating
}
```

Then, if you want them to be serialized as string inside your JSON responses, just add the correct converter to the Web API JSON serializer instance:

```
 config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add
            (new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
```

Assuming `config` is your `HttpConfiguration` instance.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I got the serialize working by adding an empty constructor for each enum class. I will talk to my boss if we should refactor or how we should proceed!